# Exchanger : JVM never stops

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronize

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Exchanger<String> exchanger = new Exchanger<String>();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + exchanger.exchange("this came from subthread"));
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("interrupted while waiting for message");
            }
        }
    }).start();

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + exchanger.exchange("this came from main thread"));
    String s = exchanger.exchange("this came from main thread");
}
```

**Output**

```
mainthis came from subthread
Thread-0this came from main thread
```

Why does the JVM never quit here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one exchange point in your thread, but 2 exchange points in your main thread. So the second exchange: `String s = exchanger.exchange("this came from main thread");` waits forever and prevents the JVM from exiting. If you add a print statement after that line, you will see it does not get executed.

If you add a second exchange in your thread, the program will exit:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + exchanger.exchange("this came from subthread"));
        exchanger.exchange("allow JVM to exit here");
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("interrupted while waiting for message");
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the last line in main method is removed?

Comment: of course,this is such a stupid question from me.. one time when copy paste has caused this error... should have seen my codeposting here.. on eclipse, somehow those 2 lines were pasted side by side, so I completely missed it.. :(

Comment: @assylias thought so and tried it. But it did nt exit jvm, although what you mentioned worked.

Comment: @SubinS I just tried and it does work. Basically, as long as you have the same number of exchanges in the main thread and the other thread, the JVM will exit.

Comment: @assylias  :-), I have no idea why, but commmenting last line did nt exit jvm, however if i remove that line it works. Some thing to do with my eclipse I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The last line:

```
String s = exchanger.exchange("this came from main thread");
```

offers `"this came from main thread"` for exchange with some other thread, but there's no other thread to make a counter offer.